# getting warning when i use sudo apt-get update command

Tags: apt, updates, 15.10

I am getting error when i use `sudo apt-get update` command

```
Get:58 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/multiverse Translation-en [28 B]
Get:59 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/restricted Translation-en [28 B]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com wily-backports/universe Translation-en [1,390 B]
Fetched 32.5 MB in 23s (1,379 kB/s)                                            
Reading package lists... Done
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

I am not familiar with Ubuntu if any one know how to solve please help me

I'm using 64bit-Ubuntu (15.10)  ;

This is my source list look like:

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily main restricted universe multiverse

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily-backports main restricted universe multiverse

###### Ubuntu Partner Repo
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu wily partner

###### Ubuntu Extras Repo
#deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily main
#deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu wily main
```

Comment: @mikewhatever sorry mike i am new to ubuntu on seeing the answer i am not able to understand what is going on is it possible to explain to as a beginner level  .

Comment: please copy the contents of your /etc/sources.list .Then we know where is the exact problem lies.

Comment: @bhordupur where can i fine sources.list what command i shoud use

Comment: @bhordupur i have updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

Look at your `/etc/sources.list` (or the files in `/etc/sources.list.d`) and remove or fix those lines that cause the error.

This answer should help.

[How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists)

Comment: how to view the sources.list in my ubuntu

Comment: @MohanGopi Go to your contents of the file system (Below **Devices**).
Look at your etc/ sources.list

Comment: i have updated source list

Comment: @MohanGopi If the error is Still showing than open **System Settings** go to **Software & Updates** A dialog box will open click on other updates and enable **http:/dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main** if not enabled 
If u are not getting that show that box image and update your question

Comment: thanks i solved this error by mikewhatever stack overflow question that he shared

Answer (score 3):

This happens a lot when installing Chrome via the Google repository. The reason for this is that most people add the source manually as a lot of websites do suggest is.

Problem with this is that after installing Chrome it automatically adds and configures `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list` causing a duplicate.

The fix is simply removing the manual repository you added and the problem should be gone. I would recommend checking `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` for the second duplicate. In my case the file was called `google.list`.

Comment: thanks i solved this error by mikewhatever stack overflow question that he shared